# When Bower and NPM Become Aware of New Code on Github

Tags: node.js, github, npm, bower

I am wondering when Bower and NPM package managers become aware of code updates to a package repository on Github. That is, is it somehow instantaneous and the latest code becomes available for download?

Or is there a separate process through which the developers need to notify Bower and NPM of changes made to the package?

Comment: For npm package, you can use command `npm deprecate` to deprecate a version so that it print warning message when someone install the version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bower and npm both use registries to identify available versions for packages, when you use bower/npm `install` `update` etc. the clients actually access the registries first to get the updated list of packages.

For npm, you can see the registry format [here](https://registry.npmjs.org/-/all) - this is the 'main' registry which points to individual packages. additional info on each package is available like this: `https://registry.npmjs.org/<package name>`
each such entry in the registry holds a json descriptor of that package with all available versions for it etc.

For bower the registry is available [here](https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages) you can also search it with `https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/<package name>` - each registry entry here points to a location where the `bower.json` file that describes the package is available.  versions are retrieved for the `git` repo's data.

Comment: Do you know how one goes about adding a package to either of those? Is there some standard procedure?

Comment: There's already very good documentation for both [npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages) and [bower](https://bower.io/docs/creating-packages/#register) on how to do that.